# Async Netty HttpServer and HttpClient

Tags: http, netty

I have been exploring Netty for the past days, as I am writing a quick and tight HTTP server that should receive lots of requests, and Netty's HTTP server implementation is quite simple and does the job.

My next step is as part of the request handling, I need to launch an HTTP request to an external web server. My intuition is to implement an asynchronous client that can send a lot of requests simultaneously, but I am a little confused as what is the right approach. My understanding is that Netty server uses a worker thread for each incoming message, therefore that worker thread would not be freed to accept new messages until my handler finishes its work. 
Here is the punch: even if I have an asynchronous HTTP client in hand, it won't matter if I need to wait for each response and process it back with my server handler - the same worker thread would remain blocking all this time. The alternative is to use the async nature of the client, returning a future object quickly to release the thread and place a listener (meaning I have to return 200 or 202 status to the client), and check my future object to indicate when the response is received and I can push it to the client.

Does this make sense? Am I way off with my assumptions? What is a good practice to implement such kind of Netty acceptor server + external client with high concurrency?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're asking about Netty 4.

Netty configured with a ServerBootstrap will have a fixed number of worker threads that it uses to accept requests and execute the channel, like so:

```
Two threads accepting / processing requests
bootstrap.group(NioEventLoopGroup(2))

One thread accepting requests, two threads processing.
bootstrap.group(NioEventLoopGroup(1), NioEventLoopGroup(1))
```

In your case, you have a channel includes a bunch of Http Codec decoding/encoding stuff and your own handler which itself makes an outgoing Http request. You're right that you don't want to block the server from accepting incoming requests, or decoding the incoming Http message, and there are two things you can do to mitigate that, you've struck on the first already.

Firstly, you want to use an Async netty client to make the outgoing requests, have a listener write the response to the original requests channel when the outgoing request returns. This means you don't block and wait, meaning you can handle many more concurrent outgoing requests than the number of threads available to process those requests.

Secondly, you can have your custom handler run in its own EventExecutorGroup, which means it runs in a separate threadpool from the acceptor / http codec channel handlers, like so:

```
// Two separate threads to execute your outgoing requests..
EventExecutorGroup separateExecutorGroup new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(2);

bootstrap.childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
        .... http codec stuff .... 
        pipeline.addLast(separateExecutorGroup, customHandler);
    }
};
```

Meaning your outgoing requests don't hog the threads that would be used for accepting / processing incoming ones.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. With the first option, when the response is handled by the listener which thread / thread pool is being used?         And, with the second option, I actually see I can decide to draw the line between 'critical/must-have handling' which blocks, and other logic I do not want to block - that can be handled as the example suggests. Is my understanding correct?